# Open an Access form and filter the data

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a table "tblPlantData". There is an attribute "Plant" which should be filtered for different people. Some should just see data from "PlantA" others data from "PlantB"

These people use different buttons to open the form where data is shown.

When I am using
`DoCmd.OpenForm "plantForm", , , "(Plant = 'PlantA')"`

The user is able to use the filter to show data from PlantB.
I don't want to disable filtering for the user.

I could use different queries that are filtered for different forms, but this just feels wrong.

Anybody got an idea?

Comment: Don't have to use different forms, use one form but use VBA to set RecordSource with different static filter SQL statement.

Comment: "This just feels wrong" What feels wrong about it? Does something about it not meet your objective criteria?

Comment: @TylerH it's not DRY anymore and and with this maintainability isn't that good. So right now, it would be okay, but after the next changes it would hurt ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

June7's recommendation from the comment to do something like this worked fine:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmPlant"
Forms!frmPlant.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM tblPlant WHERE  plant = 'PlantA'"
```